# Load non-minified dependency in NPM

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm

I'm using a third party JavaScript library that I want to step into using the debugger in VS Code. The project is a Vue.js SPA and has a number of dependencies in my package.json file. I can see in node_modules that under lib it has a .min.js file and a standard .js file.

When I run the application it loads the minified file but this makes it a lot harder to debug. I'm wanting to load the non-minified file instead. I can't seem to find any information on this as my searches have mostly brought up how to minify JS files and include them as dependencies in NPM. I was hoping I would be able to just switch over to using the source debug file rather than the production release. I have tried renaming the .min file to see if the other would be picked up instead but no luck.

Is there a way to run the application in debug mode for dependencies? Or specify a different file for your NPM dependencies?